# Can I put a fragement in a viewpager in an extra container?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-framelayout

Is it possible to put one of the fragments in a viewpager inside a framelayout? My idea was to do something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

What I would to do is have all fragments in the viewpager, except for one, that should in the `FrameLayout` container which itself is a page in the viewpager.

How can I do that if it is possible at all? Or, is there another approach to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to break the pattern of the `ViewPager`. What are you trying to achieve? There might be an alternative method.

Comment: It is impossible 'cause of ViewPager behavior. ViewPager can't hold static fragments.