# How can I animate a Fragment inside a viewpager?

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have got a viewpager that hosts two Fragments. Now I would like to replace one of the Fragments on a button click. How can I animate this replacement? (e.g. using the flip-card effect)

Since it is difficult two put all my code in here, this is what I basically use
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Comment: similar question.. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22170784/can-i-put-a-fragement-in-a-viewpager-in-an-extra-container)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can animate it using a [PageTransformer](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer)

Or, if you want the animation on replacing a fragment, you can [set a custom animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations%28int,%20int%29) on the `FragmentTransaction`

Comment: can I use pagetransformer to animate my replacement?

Comment: There's two things here. `PageTransformer` will animate the transition between the pages in the `ViewPager`. `setCustomAnimation` will animate `Fragment` transactions.

Comment: the problem with `setCustomAnimation` is that if I want to use the flip-card effect, then I have to specify a container that contains the fragment which is to replaced with the animation. however, my fragment is just atttached to a viewpager and is not inside a special container

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I would also like to replace the fragment in the ViewPager with a card flip animation, but like you say - the fragment transaction is all handled by the ViewPager so there's no access to the container?